# Iterate Select object by name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello i have followed Select object:

```
<select id="additionalDataForm.motoForm.cascoForm.ownerClaims.claimsLastYears" name="additionalDataForm.motoForm.cascoForm.ownerClaims.claimsLastYears" 
class="w-65 me2-casco-claims-last-years">
 <option value="">-- choose--</option>
 <option value="0">0</option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3 and more</option>
</select>
```

When I try to get this object by jQuery

```
$('additionalDataForm.motoForm.cascoForm.ownerClaims.claimsLastYears');
```

or
    $('select#additionalDataForm.motoForm.cascoForm.ownerClaims.claimsLastYears');

I'm getting []..

So I try to get it from name by:

```
var select = $("select[name='additionalDataForm.motoForm.cascoForm.ownerClaims.claimsLastYears']")
```

And that's work and i have select object in select variable

Next I need to iterate each option so I'm trying to get options collection to iterate but

```
select.options or     
        $("select[name='additionalDataForm.motoForm.cascoForm.ownerClaims.claimsLastYears']").options
```

give my undefined..
and I don't know how to iterate each options elements in my select, I have no idea what it happens it can be because my element ID have commas "." ? I can't fix name because it is auto generated by spring and it must be posted to server with right name;

Comment: Rename the `<select>` because that's pretty awful

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Depends on the use case.

Comment: @JibiAbraham: There's no regex here.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I meant the Sizzle regex

Comment: @JibiAbraham: Oh, that selector will be passed straight to the underlying browser's engine on anything vaguely recent (which might also use regex). But that's not the point, the point is that the `.` is defined in the CSS selectors specification as introducing a class selector.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Fact of the matter is, I made an unhelpful comment, ONLY to point out the perils of regex. jQuery won't pick up this id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to select element by ID having complex name is to use native JavaScript DOM method:

```
$("option", document.getElementById("additionalDataForm.motoForm.cascoForm ..."))
   .each(function() {
      // ...
   });
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/xF9qt/

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("#additionalDataForm\\.motoForm\\.cascoForm\\.ownerClaims\\.claimsLastYears options")
```

The `.`s in your `id`, give jQuery the impression that it is a class selector when it is not. To tell jQuery to not consider it as a class selector, you need to escape the dots.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Explanation provided :)

Comment: @VisioN - It works if you put 2 backslashes before each `.`, don;t know why it requires 2 of them though! Where is this documented? Answer corrected.

Comment: @techfoobar: *"It works if you put 2 backslashes before each `.`, don't know why it requires 2 of them though!"* The first one makes the backslash actually part of the string, rather than introducing a string escape sequence. So for the selector engine to see a (single) backslash, you have to put two in the string literal. Updated (working) fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wtKQL/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Ahh, right. Yes, that makes sense. The first \ is used up by the JS parser while parsing the source, leaving one \ to go through to the selector engine. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: That didn't work for me $('select#additionalDataForm.\\motoForm.\\cascoForm.\\ownerClaims.\\claimsLastYears') return [] in console

Comment: The \\ shoud come *before* the . not after it. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wtKQL/2/

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$("select[name='additionalDataForm.motoForm.cascoForm.ownerClaims.claimsLastYears']")[0].options
```

Comment: There's no need to use the attribute selector instead of the id selector.